# Put pageview inside listview builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a little app were i am putting pageview inside listview but the pageview is not scrolling. Here is my code:

```
PageView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    controller: _controller,
    itemCount: _pages.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        child: _pages[index % _pages.length],
        onTap: (){
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => photoView(images: widget.imageUrls,
                initialPage: index, key: UniqueKey(),));
        },
      );


    },
    onPageChanged: (int p) {
      setState(() {
        page = p;
      });
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Have you try to wrap your `PageView` with `SingleChildScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: page,
                  itemCount: verseChapter.length + 1,
                  physics: chapterNumber == 1
                      ? const RightBlockedScrollPhysics()
                      : const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, key) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: verse.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            int i = 0;
                            toggleSelection();
                            setState(() {
                              highlightIndex[i] = -1;
                              showMenu = false;
                              i++;
                            });

                            print(setVerse);
                            print(setPlace);
                          },
                          onLongPress: () {
                            print(highlightIndex);
                            setState(() {
                              highlightIndex.add(index);

                              showMenu = true;
                              setPlace = '${taDetails[index]}';
                              setVerse =
                                  '${(index + 1).toString()}. ${verse[index].toString()}';
                              backupVerse = verse[index];

                              bookmarkVerse.add(verse[index].toString());
                              print(bookmarkVerse);
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.all(ComponentSize.paddingall),
                            color: highlightIndex.contains(index)
                                ? Colors.grey
                                : _appcolor,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Text(
                                  (index + 1).toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(color: _fontcolor),
                                ),
                                title: Text(verse[index].toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: _fontcolor,
                                        height: 1.4,
                                        fontSize: fontSized,
                                        fontFamily: language == 'Tamil'
                                            ? 'TamlBible_001'
                                            : 'Roboto')),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  onPageChanged: (int chapter) {
                    if (chapterNumber == 1) {
                      setState(() {
                        versePrevious = true;
                        verseNext = false;
                      });
                    } else {
                      if (chapterNumber > 1) {
                        setState(() {
                          versePrevious = false;
                          verseNext = false;
                        });
                      }
                    }

                    setState(() {
                      chapterNumber = chapter;
                    });

                    verseDetails(chapterNumber);
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?